# How to display images in Flutter app from Django Rest API?

Tags: android, django, flutter, api, django-rest-framework

I have problems with displaying images, that are saved in my database in Django Rest API. This is my postman output for the API:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "firstshow",
        "image": "/media/images/firstshow.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "secondshow",
        "image": "/media/images/secondshow.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "thirdshow",
        "image": "/media/images/thirdshow.jpg"
    }
]
```

This is my model:

```
class ShowsModel{
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? image;
  ShowsModel({this.id, this.name, this.image});
   ShowsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    image = json['image'];
  }

  static List<ShowsModel> showsFromSnapshot(List showsSnapshot) {
    return showsSnapshot.map((data) {
      return ShowsModel.fromJson(data);
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

I have created promocard widget, which requires imageUrl. My homepage uses promocard slider widget, which returns 3 promocards.

```
class PromoCardSlider extends StatelessWidget {
  const PromoCardSlider({Key? key, required this.showsList}) : super(key: key);
  final List<ShowsModel> showsList;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 200,
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 3,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
              return  promoCard(
                imageUrl: showsList[index].image![0]);
           
            }));
  }
}
```

On this line `imageUrl: showsList[index].image![0]);` I get error: `Exception has occurred. RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update you code with this

```html
class PromoCardSlider extends StatelessWidget {
  const PromoCardSlider({Key? key, required this.showsList}) : super(key: key);
  final List<ShowsModel> showsList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: showsList.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return promoCard(imageUrl:"Set your base URl" showsList[index].image);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this code `return const promoCard(imageUrl: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/media/images/firstshow.jpg');` and it worked. Any ideas how can I display these images from database?

Answer (score 0):

This error is occur: character at index 0 ([0]) in the image string, which is not valid in this case.

Implement accordingly as below code:

```
class PromoCardSlider extends StatelessWidget {
  const PromoCardSlider({Key? key, required this.showsList}) : super(key: key);
  final List<ShowsModel> showsList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: showsList.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return Image.network(showsList[index].image!);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using this code, but now I receive this error `No host specified in URI file:///media/images/firstshow.jpg` and it rethrows me to image.dart file

Comment: @amyhawks your url is local path url. It must be your url is start with http or http. If url is network url then use image.network and if your url is local then use image.file

Comment: Oooh I see. My images are uploaded on local Django API database. What should I do?

Comment: I just tried this code `return const promoCard(imageUrl: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/media/images/firstshow.jpg');` and it worked. Any ideas how can I display these images from database?